# Translation of natural language to relational proposition

Tags: logic, logic-translation

Here are some preconditions:

1. *unary relation constant*: person, celebrity, governor
2. *binary relation constant*: knows$(x,y)$ means $x$ knows $y,$ differ$(x,y)$ means $x$ is different to $y$

I have 2 translation questions; are my answers correct?

i)  **There is no celebrity or a person that knows any governor.**
$$ \text{∀x.∃y.((celebrity(x) ∨ person(x) ∧ governor(y)) → ¬knows(x, y)}$$

ii) **Every person knows three celebrities.**
$$  \text{∀w.∃x.∃y.∃z.(person(w) ∧ celebrity(x) ∧ celebrity(y) ∧ celebrity(z)}\\\text{∧ knows(w, x) ∧ knows(w, y) ∧ knows(w, z))}$$

Comment: For the 1st one, there should be another  right bracket after person(x) . And it is better to use \land, which gives $\land$ , than ^. Otherwise it's fine.

Comment: Click on the circled "?" on the top bar (far right)  and choose Help Center. On the Help Center page, middle column, under "Our Model" , click on "How Do I Format Mathematics Here?"

Comment: nice, thanks for your answer and the recommendations too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **There is no celebrity or a person that knows any governor.**
   $$∀x.∃y.((\text{celebrity}(x) ∨ \text{person}(x) \land
   \text{governor}(y)) → ¬\text{knows}(x, y).$$

   Correction:

   $$∀x ∀y\;\bigg((\big(\text{celebrity}(x) ∨ \text{person}(x)\big)
   \land \text{governor}(y)) → ¬\text{knows}(x, y)\bigg).$$
2. **Every person knows three celebrities.**

   $$∀w.∃x.∃y.∃z.(\text{person}(w) \land \text{celebrity}(x) \land
   \text{celebrity}(y) \land \text{celebrity}(z) \\\land \text{knows}(w,
   x) \land \text{knows}(w, y) \land \text{knows}(w, z)).$$

   Your translation is actually equivalent to $$\;∀w \;\text{person}(w) \land  ∀w ∃x\;\bigg(\text{celebrity}(x) \land \text{knows}(w, x)\bigg),$$ i.e., "Everything is a person, each of whom knows some celebrity."

   Correction: $$∀p ∃x ∃y ∃z ∀c\;(\text{person}(p)\to \bigg(x\neq y\land y\neq z\land x\neq z  \\\land (\big(c=x\lor c=y\lor c=z\big) \to\big(\text{celebrity}(c)\land\text{knows}(p, c)\big) )\bigg)).$$

P.S. For #2, if the statement becomes "every person knows **exactly** three celebrities", then just change the final $\to$ to $\leftrightarrow.$